# Ubuntu partion lost after update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

I had a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation (in a dual boot installation with Windows 7) which was running well for 6 month or more. Then in July I let run the Ubuntu Updates once more again and then after a restart I had no GRUB boot loader anymore. A part of the updates was a message box which recommended me strongly to encrypt my harddisk (system partition) which I did (what the bloody hell to include such thing in Upuntu Update without that it works properly).

In the result, when I started my notebook again I got the grub-rescue-mode:

`grub rescue> _`

With the result, that I can see my partitions, but there is no partition with GRUB anymore.

I start the system now with the Live-CD and I get the following partitions shown:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK5076GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos   

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  210MB  209MB   primary   ntfs         boot
 2      210MB   157GB  157GB   primary   ntfs
 3      157GB   500GB  343GB   extended
 5      157GB   221GB  64.0GB  logical
 6      221GB   230GB  8095MB  logical
 7      230GB   500GB  271GB   logical   ntfs
```

The partition with my Ubuntu was in Partition 5 (dev/sda5) but there is nothing known anymore:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount: block device /dev/sda5 is write-protected, mounting read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda5' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Even if it would be encrypted with LUKS (I would have a password):

```
root@ubuntu:~# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 /mnt
Device /dev/sda5 is not a valid LUKS device.
```

I let run the Boot-Repair-Tool to to make a pastbin of the system (only analyze, no repair):
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12416455/

The interesting parts are:

```
sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

and:

```
Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       409,599       407,552   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             409,600   307,609,599   307,200,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         307,611,646   976,771,071   669,159,426   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         307,611,648   432,609,279   124,997,632  83 Linux
/dev/sda6         432,611,328   448,421,887    15,810,560  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7         448,423,936   976,771,071   528,347,136   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
```

Do have anybody an idea, how I get my Ubuntu partion restored and mounted again? It would mean a work of a few days to reinstall my hole development environment again...

Unfortunately, the saved text with this Ubuntu-Update-message is on the lost partition.

Thanks for any help in advance.
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Grub can not read an encrypted partition. Encrypting the root partition requires a specially set up /boot partition that is not encrypted so that grub can boot, mount and decrypt the root partition.

This is not something done by an update. You likely acquired some form f malware/virus. A reinstall is the easiest recourse.